# MySQLdb execute timeout

Tags: python, mysql, timeout

Sometimes in our production environment occurs situation when connection between service (which is python program that uses MySQLdb) and mysql server is flacky, some packages are lost, some black magic happens and .execute() of MySQLdb.Cursor object never ends (or take great amount of time to end).

This is very bad because it is waste of service worker threads. Sometimes it leads to exhausting of workers pool and service stops responding at all.

So the question is: Is there a way to interrupt MySQLdb.Connection.execute operation after given amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

if the communication is such a problem, consider writing a 'proxy' that receives your SQL commands over the flaky connection and relays them to the MySQL server on a reliable channel (maybe running on the same box as the MySQL server).  This way you have total control over failure detection and retrying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyse exactly what the problem is. MySQL connections should eventually timeout if the server is gone; TCP keepalives are generally enabled. You may be able to tune the OS-level TCP timeouts.

If the database is "flaky", then you definitely need to investigate how. It seems unlikely that the database really is the problem, more likely that networking in between is.

If you are using (some) stateful firewalls of any kind, it's possible that they're losing some of the state, thus causing otherwise good long-lived connections to go dead.

You might want to consider changing the idle timeout parameter in MySQL; otherwise, a long-lived, unused connection may go "stale", where the server and client both think it's still alive, but some stateful network element in between has "forgotten" about the TCP connection. An application trying to use such a "stale" connection will have a long wait before receiving an error (but it should eventually).